# Is $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ under trace norm homeomorphic to some $\mathbb R^m$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, lie-groups

I've often seen proofs that invoke the Heine-Borel theorem to show that certain matrix groups are compact. They view the matrix groups (such as $SO(n)$ as 
$\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and then go on to prove them as closed and bounded, which proves that they are compact).

Is a similar proof strategy possible when we are considering matrices using trace norms? In particular, I wish to show that a certain subclass of matrices of $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ is compact **under trace norm**. Is there a homeomorphism from $(GL_n(\mathbb C), \text{trace norm})$ to some $(\mathbb R^m, \text{euclidian norm})$?

Comment: No but $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$

Comment: Is that under the standard topology or the one induced by the trace norm?

Comment: They´re the same topology

Comment: How does one prove that? I'd greatly appreciate a reference :) So, if I get this right, I can look at complex $n \times n$ matrices under trace norm as the same topologically as some open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$? So, can I then use Heine-Borel on some subset $M \subset \text{complex matrices}$ to prove that they are compact? I would greatly appreciate a reference on this topic, I'm unfortunately unable to find much.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: The key words are "equivalence of norms in finite dimension" or something like that

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help, I'll try googling this :)

Comment: @Max Open subset of $\mathbb{C}^{n^2} \approx \mathbb{R}^{2n^2}$.

Comment: @PaulFrost yes of course, I hope it was clear to the OP that it was a typo !

Comment: @Max Probably yes, and the precise dimension is anyway irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

For any $m>0$, $\mathbb{R}^m$ is contractile (i.e. has the homotopy type of a point) while $GL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ has the same homotopy type as $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ (because of the polar decomposition). But $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ isn't contractile in general.

Therefore $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $GL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ can't be homeomorphic.

Comment: Thanks. What if I allow subsets of $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: Then yes, for obvious reasons : as @Max argues, $GL_n(C)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}=\mathbb{R}^{2n^2}$

Comment: Hm, I see. Thanks! What if I weaken then $GL_n(\mathbb C)$  requirement, such that they are just _some_ subset of the complex matrices under trace norm (not the invertible ones)?

Comment: Then it will depend on the kind of subsets your considering... By the way, the fact that your considering trace norm is irrelevant : the topology of finite dimensional vector spaces (and subspaces thereof) is notoriously independant of the norm that induces it.

Comment: I see, that is quite helpful. Could you point me to a reference that shows the equivalence of the topologies induced by the trace norm and the regular euclidian-style norm? Would be greatly appreciated! (@Max mentioned googling "equivalence of norms in finite dimension", but a concrete reference would be nice)